# How to get the 4 coordinates of a rectangle from 3 coordinates?

Tags: geometry, leaflet, qgis

I want to create a function that allows user to draw rectangle from 3 points (blue points):

- The first two points will form an edge (width).
- The third point will determine the height.

I need this custom draw function in leaflet, however leaflet's default rectangle is created with 2 diagonal points: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#rectangle.

I need to calculate one of the green points but my small brain can't seem to figure it out :P

PS/EDIT: The rectangle might be angled, this is what makes it challenging

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Leaflet's default rectangle is created with 2 diagonal points
>
> [...]
>
> The rectangle might be angled, this is what makes it challenging

Be aware that Leaflet's `L.Rectangle` is created from a `L.LatLngBounds`, a bounding box **in which the edges are implicitly aligned to the coordinate grid**. Don't use bounding boxes, and rely on `L.Polygon` instead, providing all four points.

---

Let A and B be the points of the base of the rectangle, and C be the point on the top. Assuming all points are Javascript structures of the form `{x: Number, y: Number}`, and assuming that you're working in an euclidean plane (i.e. not on the surface of a geoid),

First, [calculate the distance from a point to a line defined by the other two points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points), i.e. the distance from C to the line defined by AB. Let that be `distance` (note that it's equal to "height" in your diagram):

```
var distance = Math.abs( 
    (A.y - B.y) * C.x  -  (A.x - B-x) * C.y  +  B.x * A.y  -  B.y * A.x ) 
  ) / Math.sqrt(
    Math.pow(B.y - A.y, 2) + Math.pow(B.x - A.x, 2)
  );
```

Then, let AB be the vector from A to B

```
var AB = {  x: B.x - A.x,   y: B.y - A.y };
```

(Note that the length of AB is equal to "width" in your diagram)

Calculate a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) perpendicular to AB:

```
var perpendicular = {x: -AB.y, y: AB.x}
var perpendicularSize = Math.sqrt(AB.x * AB.x + AB.y * AB.y);
var unit = {x: perpendicular.x / perpendicularSize, y: perpendicular.y / perpendicularSize};
```

Multiply that unit vector by the distance from C to AB to get the vectors for the "sides" of your rectangle:

```
var sideVector = { x: unit.x * distance, y: unit.y * distance };
```

...and create new points D and E by offsetting A and B by the vector for the sides of the rectangle:

```
var D = { x: A.x + sideVector.x, y: A.y + sideVector.y };
var E = { x: B.x + sideVector.x, y: B.y + sideVector.y };
```

...And your rectangle is now defined by the points ABDE. Note that C is in the line defined by points DE.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much, now that I read your answer, I vaguely remember doing this in school long ago hahaha. I have further question if you don't mind. Since I eventually want to draw the rectangle on leaflet map, would the projection affect the shape? I need the final shape to be a rectangle with 4 right angles. My use case is to draw an angled rectangle; initially I went with a 2 steps method, draw rectangle then rotate, but the rotate plugins that I could find distorts the rectangle due to the projection. Which is why I wanted to use the bounds, what do you suggest?

Comment: Yes, projections can screw your calculations. That's why I added the "assuming that you're working in an euclidean plane" bit. Geometry on the surface of a geoid (or on the surface of a sphere, for that matter) is very different from euclidean geometry, e.g. the angles of a triangle can add up to more than 180° (think triangle with vertices at north pole, equator at prime meridian, equator at 90° meridian), so you cannot ever have a rectangle with four 90° angles.

Comment: In practical terms, you should either redefine your problem in terms of geodesic geometry, or project the data onto a known [CRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system) (preferably one based on a [conformal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Projections_by_preservation_of_a_metric_property) adequate for your data) and work on that CRS as if it was an euclidean plane.

Comment: I see. I understand now. Thank you so much for explaining! It's interesting and enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

For Python:

```
#Given three points fit a rectangle

import math 
a,b,c=[1,4],[3,4],[3,10] #Sample numbers

#Distance from dot C to line AB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Line_defined_by_two_points)
distance= abs((b[1]-a[1])*c[0] - (b[0]-a[0])*c[1] + b[0]*a[1] - b[1]*a[0] ) / math.sqrt((b[1]-a[1])**2 + (b[0]-a[0])**2)
print(distance)
#let AB be the vector from A to B
ab=[b[0]-a[0],b[1]-a[1]]

#unit vector perpendicular to AB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector)
perpendicularSize = math.sqrt(ab[0]**2+ab[1]**2)
unit = [-ab[1]/perpendicularSize ,ab[0]/perpendicularSize]

#Multiply that unit vector by the distance from C to AB to get the vectors for the "sides" of your rectangle
sideVector = [unit[0]*distance,unit[1]*distance]

#create new points D and E by offsetting A and B by the vector for the sides of the rectangle
d=[a[0]+sideVector[0],a[1]+sideVector[1]]
e=[b[0]+sideVector[0],b[1]+sideVector[1]]

print(e,d)  #[3.0, 10.0] [1.0, 10.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming coordinates of those 3 dots are provided,
- 2, 5 (first point)
- 5, 5 (second point)
- x, 8 (third point)

the first green will take x from one of the first two point let's say from the first one => 2, and y from the third point => 8
so the first green point is at 2,8

the second will take x from the second point => 5, and y from the third point => 8
so the second green point is at 5,8

I'm not sure if I understand the answer correctly tho.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Yes, this is the base case but it will only work if the rectangle is not at an angle (the edge formed by point 1 and point 2 is parallel to x-axis). However, the rectangle might be angled. So it will be a little more complex.

Comment: Ahh I see, that's a lot more complicated. Now I wanna know the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

assuming edge1 = [x1,y1]
   , edge2 = [x2,y2]

```
def calculate_edges (edge1,edge2,height)
    edge3 [0] = edge1[0]          //x3
    edge3 [1] = edge1[1] + height //y3
    edge4 [0] = edge2[0]          //x4
    edge4 [1] = edge2[1] + height //y4
return edge3,edge4
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. Yes, this is the base case but it will only work if the rectangle is not at an angle (the edge formed by point 1 and point 2 is parallel to x-axis). However, the rectangle might be angled. So it will be a little more complex

Comment: here you have to make a landmark transformation (1-assume edge1 is your new landmark, 2 - calculate the coordinates of the other edges using the algo i implemented, 3 - calculate the matrix of transformation (from the new  landmark to the original) and '-finally find coordinates of the different edges in the original landmark )[https://imgur.com/a/WNwIMJB]